# Failed to add a package to MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I try to add a package (`foiltex`) to my MiKTeX Installation - without success so far.

I have run the required `latex foiltex.ins` and `latex foiltex.dtx`.

What I have tried:

1. Added `foiltex` to `installationDir\tex\latex\` where all the other packages are, then run `initexmf --update-fndb`. The logfile `initexmf.log` shows that the directory is parsed:

   > initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (installationDir)...

   But `foiltex` is not loaded (checked with `mpm --verify=foiltex`).
2. Added another root directory `C:\temp\MiKTeX`, put `foiltex` into  `C:\temp\MiKTeX\tex\latex\`, then run `initexmf --update-fndb`. Again, the log shows that this new directory is parsed. `foiltex` is still not there.
3. Executed `mpm --install=foiltex`. Log file says:

   > FATAL mpmcli - The requested package is unknown.

What else can I try to add `foiltex` to my MiKTeX installation? (Unfortunately my box is behind a firewall and has no access to all the LaTeX repositiories on the internet...)

Comment: Are you sure your document is calling it correctly? The class is called foils.cls not foiltex.

Comment: Beside this: the right way to install it is b).  You shouldn't put local files in the installation directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response.

Comment: I not even came to the point to add it to a document. As long as mpm does not know the package, I thougth it's not worth trying...

Comment: mpm only knows the packages packaged and installed by miktex, it will never say something about such manually installed packages.